# Raspberry Pi Server

Tags: swift, uitableview, server, raspberry-pi3

I'm 13 and I started thinking of making an app for my school where people can just talk about stuff and post things. I was wondering if I can use my Raspberry Pi 3 as a server and how many people it would support if people are posting messages(probably not pictures)that are maybe 180 characters long and users can also see other people's posts. Any ideas?

Comment: The short answer is yes it can.
The amount it can support will be restricted by the specs of your Raspberry Pi (Ram? CPU? Has Heatsink?) and your Internet Service Provider.

Comment: It has a Heatsink and we have Xfinity internet. I think it's the newest one.

Comment: Ok, which service you have with Xfinity? From what I can see they can go from 10mbps to 350mbps (According to their internet services page [https://www.xfinity.com/learn/internet-service])

Comment: Ok, my dad says it's about 50 mbps. There's about 750 kids in my school. The pi can handle this right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not an expert. The calculations made are theoretical and most probably need to be double checked.

I assumed that the messages could be up to 175 characters (additional control characters, user id, ...), that there would be up to 1000 users (friends outside of school, family, ...) and that your characters are encoded in a 4 byte format.

[image: Estimations of network load]

In theory, your network and the Raspberry Pi can manage the operations. I would just recommend being extra careful about security and verifying if you have a Static IP address (else get a static domain name/IP).